# Looking for some guidance on rewriting URL's using PHP and/or htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want rewrite the URL using PHP and/or .htaccess for when a user goes to http://mysite.com/profile they are acctually accessing http://mysite.com/index.php?page=profile

I'm a litte confused how to do this. Is this practice a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

If mod rewrite is activated this should work in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error page when doing this.
404 Not Found The server can not find the requested page: mysite.com/profile (port 80)

Comment: wird das modul in der httpd.conf geladen?